# What is Every Single Command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how what the commands in minecraft are that includes cheats.  The help command does not state every command.

Answer (score 1):

[The help command does in fact show all the commands.](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Commands)

Are you going through all the pages? Example: /help page 3

Comment: Yes I have gone through all

Comment: Then you have seen all the commands.

Comment: You are probably used to bukkit and expected more, but with the given commands one can already accomplish a lot